# Almost like a prequel, but not quite

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

I'm writing a series of horror novellettes and in order to introduce the main characters, I've decided to write a few short stories. These stories will function as intros, but I don't want to call them that. Thinking in terms of a television show, I've seen this happened, although I can't remember how it's called. What word am I searching for? Is there such a word?

Comment: ***prologue***.

Comment: you're perhaps thinking of "backstory", and similar phrases, also.

Comment: Are you thinking of the word [***pilot***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pilot)? That's not really the right analogue, although it usually does introduce the main characters.

Comment: Regarding TV, you might be thinking of ***cold open*** or ***cold opening***, but the concept doesn't really apply to the situation you describe.

Answer (score 3):

You could call those stories [**preludes**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20prelude) to your main story:

> an action or event serving as an introduction to something more
>   important.
>
> *"education cannot simply be a prelude to a career"*
>
> **synonyms:** preliminary, overture, opening, preparation, introduction, start, commencement, beginning, lead-in, precursor
>
> *"the ceasefire was a prelude to peace negotiations"*